# Count number of "True" values in boolean Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I understand that `tf.where` will return the locations of `True` values, so that I could use the result's `shape[0]` to get the number of `True`s.

However, when I try and use this, the dimension is unknown (which makes sense as it needs to be computed at runtime). So my question is, how can I access a dimension and use it in an operation like a sum?

For example:

```
myOtherTensor = tf.constant([[True, True], [False, True]])
myTensor = tf.where(myOtherTensor)
myTensor.get_shape() #=> [None, 2]
sum = 0
sum += myTensor.get_shape().as_list()[0] # Well defined at runtime but considered None until then.
```

Comment: What does `myTensor` look like?

Comment: @erip I updated with a more explicit example.

Comment: Is your expected output 2?

Comment: @erip in the case above it would be three as there are 3 Trues

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can cast the values to floats and compute the sum on them:
`tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(myOtherTensor, tf.float32))`

Depending on your actual use case you can also compute sums per row/column if you specify the reduce dimensions of the call.

Comment: Thank you! Forgot about python's Boolean equivalencies.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a cast (and the corresponding memory hit)?

Comment: Talking about memory, why float32 and not int8?

Answer (score 28):

I think this is the easiest way to do it:

```
In [38]: myOtherTensor = tf.constant([[True, True], [False, True]])

In [39]: if_true = tf.count_nonzero(myOtherTensor)

In [40]: sess.run(if_true)
Out[40]: 3
```

Comment: in v2.3.1, this is `tf.math.count_nonzero`

Answer (score 8):

Rafal's answer is almost certainly the simplest way to count the number of `true` elements in your tensor, but the other part of your question asked:

> [H]ow can I access a dimension and use it in an operation like a sum?

To do this, you can use TensorFlow's [shape-related operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shapes_and_shaping), which act on the runtime value of the tensor. For example, [`tf.size(t)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#size) produces a scalar `Tensor` containing the number of elements in `t`, and [`tf.shape(t)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) produces a 1D `Tensor` containing the size of `t` in each dimension.

Using these operators, your program could also be written as:

```
myOtherTensor = tf.constant([[True, True], [False, True]])
myTensor = tf.where(myOtherTensor)
countTrue = tf.shape(myTensor)[0]  # Size of `myTensor` in the 0th dimension.

sess = tf.Session()
sum = sess.run(countTrue)
```

Comment: thanks so much for this! would it be possible to loop through 0 to the resulting vale? It would be a single-element tensor, would it not? So I couldn't pass it to xrange() (unless xrange was extended to accept Tensors)? If this is unclear I'll ask a new question about it with more detail.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you wanting to loop through the dimensions of `myTensor` and use the size in each dimension? Perhaps this would be best addressed in a new question.

Comment: yeah, that was poorly worded. I'll write one up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817456/using-tensors-in-control-flow-and-conditional-statements

Answer (score 3):

There is a tensorflow function to count non-zero values [`tf.count_nonzero`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/count_nonzero). The function also accepts an `axis` and `keep_dims` arguments.

Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(np.random.random(100))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.count_nonzero(tf.greater(a, 0.5))))
```