# Determining if A Value is in a Set in TensorFlow

Tags: python, set, tensorflow

The `tf.logical_or`, `tf.logical_and`, and `tf.select` functions are very useful.

However, suppose you have value `x`, and you wanted to see if it was in a `set(a, b, c, d, e)`. In python you would simply write:

```
if x in set([a, b, c, d, e]):
  # Do some action.
```

As far as I can tell, the only way to do this in TensorFlow, is to have nested 'tf.logical_or' along with 'tf.equal'. I provided just one iteration of this concept below:

```
tf.logical_or(
    tf.logical_or(tf.equal(x, a), tf.equal(x, b)),
    tf.logical_or(tf.equal(x, c), tf.equal(x, d))
)
```

I feel that there must be an easier way to do this in TensorFlow. Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this related question: [Count number of "True" values in boolean Tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598371/count-number-of-true-values-in-boolean-tensor/)

You should be able to build a tensor consisting of [a, b, c, d, e] and then check if any of the rows is equal to x using `tf.equal(.)`

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Reduce_sum is the best way to go.

Comment: You can also use `tf.listdiff` to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @dga that shows only the difference, not the similar ones?

Comment: For someone new to Tensorflow it is difficult to see how your linked post addresses the OP's situation. Perhaps you could post a complete code snippet here?

Answer (score 7):

To provide a more concrete answer, say you want to check whether the last dimension of the tensor `x` contains any value from a 1D tensor `s`, you could do the following:

```
tile_multiples = tf.concat([tf.ones(tf.shape(tf.shape(x)), dtype=tf.int32), tf.shape(s)], axis=0)
x_tile = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(x, -1), tile_multiples)
x_in_s = tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(x_tile, s), -1))
```

For example, for `s` and `x`:

```
s = tf.constant([3, 4])
x = tf.constant([[[1, 2, 3, 0, 0], 
                  [4, 4, 4, 0, 0]], 
                 [[3, 5, 5, 6, 4], 
                  [4, 7, 3, 8, 9]]])
```

`x` has shape `[2, 2, 5]` and `s` has shape `[2]` so `tile_multiples = [1, 1, 1, 2]`, meaning we will tile the last dimension of `x` 2 times (once for each element in `s`) along a new dimension. So, `x_tile` will look like:

```
[[[[1 1]
   [2 2]
   [3 3]
   [0 0]
   [0 0]]

  [[4 4]
   [4 4]
   [4 4]
   [0 0]
   [0 0]]]

 [[[3 3]
   [5 5]
   [5 5]
   [6 6]
   [4 4]]

  [[4 4]
   [7 7]
   [3 3]
   [8 8]
   [9 9]]]]
```

and `x_in_s` will compare each of the tiled values to one of the values in `s`. `tf.reduce_any` along the last dim will return true if any of the tiled values was in `s`, giving the final result:

```
[[[False False  True False False]
  [ True  True  True False False]]

 [[ True False False False  True]
  [ True False  True False False]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's two solutions, we want to check if `query` is in `whitelist`

```
whitelist = tf.constant(["CUISINE", "DISH", "RESTAURANT", "ADDRESS"])
query = "RESTAURANT"

#use broadcasting for element-wise tensor operation
broadcast_equal = tf.equal(whitelist, query)

#method 1: using tensor ops
broadcast_equal_int = tf.cast(broadcast_equal, tf.int8)
broadcast_sum = tf.reduce_sum(broadcast_equal_int)

#method 2: using some tf.core API
nz_cnt = tf.count_nonzero(broadcast_equal)

sess.run([broadcast_equal, broadcast_sum, nz_cnt])
#=> [array([False, False,  True, False]), 1, 1]
```

So if the output is `> 0` then the item is in the set.

Comment: How does this work when both `query` and `whitelist` have more than one element?