# In TensorFlow, how can I assert the values of a list are in certain set?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a one-dimensional `tf.uint8` tensor `x` and want to assert that all values inside that tensor are in set `s` I define. `s` is fixed at graph definition time, so it's not a dynamically computed tensor.

In plain Python, I want to do sth. like the following:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 1, 11, 3, 5]
s = {1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13}
assert all(el in s for el in x), "This should fail, as 5 is not in s"
```

I know that I can use [`tf.Assert`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Assert) for the assertion part but I'm struggling with defining the condition part (`el in s`). What's the simplest/most canonical way to do this?

The older answer [Determining if A Value is in a Set in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34618207/3924118is) is not sufficient to me: first of all, it's complex to write down and understand, and, second, it's using a broadcasted `tf.equal`, which is more expensive computation wise than a proper set-based check.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way could be something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = [1, 2, 3, 1, 11, 3, 5]
s = {1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13}

x_t = tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.uint8)
s_t = tf.constant(list(s), dtype=tf.uint8)
# Check every value in x against every value in s
xs_eq = tf.equal(x_t[:, tf.newaxis], s_t)
# Check every element in x is equal to at least one element in s
assert_op = tf.Assert(tf.reduce_all(tf.reduce_any(xs_eq, axis=1)), [x_t])
with tf.control_dependencies([assert_op]):
    # Use x_t...
```

This creates an intermediate tensor with size `(len(x), len(s))`. If that is problematic, you could also split the problem into independent tensors, for example like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = [1, 2, 3, 1, 11, 3, 5]
s = {1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13}

x_t = tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.uint8)
# Count where each x matches each s
x_in_s = [tf.cast(tf.equal(x_t, si), tf.int32) for si in s]
# Add matches and check there is at least one match per x
assert_op = tf.Assert(tf.reduce_all(tf.add_n(x_in_s) > 0), [x_t])
```

EDIT:

Actually, since you said your values are `tf.uint8`, you can make things even better with boolean arrays:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = [1, 2, 3, 1, 11, 3, 5]
s = {1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13}

x_t = tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.uint8)
s_t = tf.constant(list(s), dtype=tf.uint8)
# One-hot vectors of values included in x and s
x_bool = tf.scatter_nd(tf.cast(x_t[:, tf.newaxis], tf.int32),
                       tf.ones_like(x_t, dtype=tf.bool), [256])
s_bool = tf.scatter_nd(tf.cast(s_t[:, tf.newaxis], tf.int32),
                       tf.ones_like(s_t, dtype=tf.bool), [256])
# Check that all values in x are in s
assert_op = tf.Assert(tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(x_bool, x_bool & s_bool)), [x_t])
```

This takes linear time and constant memory.

EDIT 2: While the last method is theoretically the best in this case, doing a couple of quick benchmarks I can only see a significant difference in performance  when I go up to hundreds of thousands of elements, and in any case the three are still quite fast with `tf.uint8`.