# How to check which elements of a tensor A are present also in a tensor B, and create a boolean mask

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow2.0

In tensorflow 2.0 I have two tensors of integers (tf.uint8), let's call them A and B.
The rank of the tensor A is arbitrary, while B is unidimensinal. 
The result that I am looking for is to get a tensor C of bools (tf.bool) such that:

(For the example suppose that A is rank 3)

- the shape of C is equal to the shape of A
- C[i,j,k] must be True if and only if A[i, j, k] is present in B

(i,j,k are indices used here just to clarify the concept)

To summerize, I need to check if the elements of A are in B, and create a mask (C) that says which elements of A are in B and which aren't.

Visual example (actually it is not code, just a visual representation of the researched behaviour):

```
 A = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]]

 B = [1,5]

 C = [[True, False, False],
     [False, True, False]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining if A Value is in a Set in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618207/determining-if-a-value-is-in-a-set-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Already read that one but I couldn't figure out a solution for my case...

Comment: How come? [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48117911/5368083) describes exactly what you've described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following. I couldn't find a way of solving this in a vectorized manner as you want this to work on any arbitrary sized A. But as long as B is not very long, this should work fine.

```
A = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

B = tf.constant([1,5])

C = tf.math.greater(tf.reduce_sum(tf.map_fn(lambda b: tf.cast(tf.math.equal(A,b), tf.int32), B), axis=0),0)
```