# Using Tensors in control flow and conditional statements

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm interested how I can use a Tensor (without a session) in control flow statements.

---

One example of what I mean by this is:

```
myTensor = tf.where(myOtherTensor) # shape == [None, 2]
numLoops = tf.shape(myTensor)[0] # Results in tensor of shape [1]
for i in xrange(numLoops):
     # ...
```

Can I pass numLoops (a tensor) to xrange()? If not, is there another way to do this?

---

Another example would be:

```
myTensor = tf.in_top_k(myOtherTensor1, myOtherTensor2, 5) # Tensor of bools
myCondition = myTensor[0] # Results in tensor of shape [1] of type bool
if myCondition:
     # ...
```

---

**My Question:** Can Tensors (without a specific session) be used in the ways outlined above?

If I had a session I could simply evaluate those single-element tensors and then use them. In the event that I don't know the specific value until runtime, there must be a way to use the values.

**Problems I could foresee:** maybe the loop would make generating the graph impossible as you don't know how many times the contained operations will be executed? But it would seem trivial to store the loop's operations and simply apply them the correct number of times, at runtime.

If anything lacks clarity, let me know and I'll provide more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow contains experimental support for in-graph control flow in [the `tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_ops` module](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py). (**N.B.** The interfaces to these ops are subject to change! Use at your own risk!)

---

Conditional support (your second case) will appear in the next release, and was recently added to the public API (if you build from source). It's currently being used in some of the libraries that ship with TensorFlow, such as the [RNN cell](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7ddf1ebfdd120409c19bd6727c18a3f283ada42c/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L109) (which use it for early stopping when the sequence length is known).

The [`tf.cond()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7ddf1ebfdd120409c19bd6727c18a3f283ada42c/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py#L599) operator takes a boolean `Tensor`, which acts as the predicate, and two lambda expressions; and returns one or more values.

Your program would look something like:

```
if_true = lambda: ...  # Value to return if `myCondition` is true
if_false = lambda: ...  # Value to return if `myCondition` is false

result = tf.cond(myCondition, if_true, if_false)
```

---

Iteration (your first case) can be handled using the [`While()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7ddf1ebfdd120409c19bd6727c18a3f283ada42c/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py#L1071) higher-order operator. Essentially, you would write your program as (in pseudocode):

```
i = 0
while i < tf.rank(myTensor):
  # ...
```

...which would approximately be represented as:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops as cfo

i = tf.constant(0)
condition = lambda i: tf.less(i, tf.rank(myTensor))
body = lambda x: ...
inital_accumulator = ...  # will be bound to `x` in first iteration of `body`.

# `result` will contain the value returned from the final iteration of `body`.
result = cfo.While(condition, body, [initial_accumulator])
```

Note that the `While()` operator requires you to specify initial values for all of the loop variables (just `initial_accumulator` in this case). Loop constants will be captured as in a normal Python lambda.